# Global figures phrase

Tags: phrase-usage

Can I use the term *global figures* to describe final totals in a personal individual balance sheet that has no global connection or reach?

Comment: What do you mean by a personal individual balance sheet? This sounds to me like un bilan global, from French, which, in English, for a person, is not a balance sheet or global. Un bilan individuel global? More context would help. It sounds like someone has high overall sales' figures, to me.

Answer (score 1):

Not really.

[global](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/global):

1. : spherical
2. : of, relating to, or involving the entire world : worldwide : *a global system of communication*; also : of or relating to a celestial body (such as the moon)
3. : of, relating to, or applying to a whole (such as a mathematical function or a computer program) : universal : *a global search of a file*

The third meaning would probably come close, but for a balance sheet it would sound a bit grand to me. *Total* would be a better choice, or even *grand total*.